# Attach and run script inside an existing tmux session

Tags: bash, cron, tmux

I want to have more control over a time consuming cron job running on a server. That is, be able to see progress, stop running code if necessary and etc..

I thought that this would be possible using a tmux session, but I can not figure out how.

I know that you can start new tmux sessions and run code inside it like this:

```
tmux new-session -d -s session_name "some code"
```

I've tried the obvious solution like this:

```
tmux new-session -s session_name
**exit session**
tmux a -t session_name "some code"
```

Is this even possible? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048740/run-or-send-a-command-to-a-tmux-pane-in-a-running-tmux-session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send the key to the tmux session:

```
tmux send -t session_name ls ENTER
```

if you need to send to a specific panel:

```
tmux send -t session_name.(panelnumber) ls ENTER
```

example:

```
tmux send -t session_name.0 ls ENTER
```

Comment: NB that "session_name" should actually be the name of the _window_ if you have multiple windows inside a session.